# I tried to animate scroll with the popup open but it does not work

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup

Hello I have a question

After popup

I had to use animate to scroll to the position I wanted.

But that code did not work.

I do not know why.

It is the code that works if it is not in the popup state.

code

```
$('.category_name_list_button').click(function (e) {
    const user_name = $("#shortcut_user_id").val();
    const url = '/wm/myshorcut/nicklist/' + user_name
    const ch = $("#current_category").text()

    $.get(url)
        .done((result) => {
            console.log("result : ", result);
            $(".category_nick_area").html(result)

            $("#CategoryModal").modal();

            $("#" + ch).css("background-color", "skyblue");

            // alert("ch : " +ch)
            //
            // $('html, body').animate({
            //     'scrollTop' : $("#"+ch).offset().top
            // });

        })
        .fail(() => {
            console.log("fail");
        })
        .always(() => {
            console.log('always');
        })
})
```

and

I've changed the class name from body to modal window class name, but it's still not.

```
            // work 
            $("#" + ch).css("background-color", "skyblue");

            // not work
            $('html, .categoynick_modal').animate({
                'scrollTop': $("#"+ch).offset().top
            });
```

modal

```
<div class="modal fade categoynick_modal" id="CategoryModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body category_nick_area">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much for letting me know how to run animate scroll with popups open or how to move to a specific location.

[image]

Comment: I dont know if its a typo error, but in your edited code, you use $("#"+ch).bottom, which should be $("#"+ch).offset().top ?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Something seems to be wrong, but I do not know yet.
I'll find out more.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the scroll to like this

```
$('html, YOUR_MODAL_DIV_ID_OR_CLASS').animate({
   'scrollTop' : $("#"+ch).offset().top
});
```

**Don't use body !**

Comment: // work 
   $("#" + ch).css("background-color", "skyblue");

   // not work
   $('html, .categoynick_modal').animate({
    'scrollTop': $("#"+ch).bottom
   });

Answer (score 1):

Unless you absolutely need to use jQuery animate function, maybe you could try this:

```
document.getElementById('CategoryModal').scrollTo({
  top: $("#"+ch).offset().top,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but The solution you provided did not work
The color is displayed, but the scroll is silent.

Comment: by silent, do you mean it scroll but with no animation ?

Comment: I just realized the categories list was inside the modal, when i saw your picture... I edited my answer. It makes more sens to scroll the modal div !